# From .json file to mongoose schema?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `.json` file that includes dictionaries(objects) and arrays.

Before, front-end just asked the the server for this `.json` file. But now I have added a mongo database. And I figured that it would be better to hold and send this data from mongo.

So I need to write a small program that would open my `.json` file, read it and store this data in mongoose schema.

**What is the propitiate way to do it?**

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A JSON file is already a perfectly suitable way to store dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just store the JSON directly, but if it's a static file and you don't expect loads of them, then you're likely just introducing more work for yourself by setting up a DB.

However, if you really want to do it that way, this is the quick-messy-and-not-production-worthy way of doing that.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({key : JSON}),
    Json = mongoose.model('JSON', schema),
    toSave = new Json({key : yourJsonObject});

toSave.save(function(err){
   'use strict';
   if (err) {
       throw err;
   }
   console.log('woo!');
})
```